# Load From byte array , Resize And Load To Stream Dosent show image in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**Sorry For Bad Title**

I have this function :

```
        public Stream PictureStream( int size = 0 )
        {
            if( size == 0 )
            {
                return new MemoryStream( PictureFile );
            }
            else
            {
                ImageFormat format = null;
                if( FileFormat == ".jpg" || FileFormat == ".jpeg" )
                {
                    format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                }
                else if( FileFormat == ".png" )
                {
                    format = ImageFormat.Png;
                }
                else
                {
                    format = ImageFormat.Png;
                }
                var ms = new MemoryStream( PictureFile );
                var returnImage = Image.FromStream( ms );
                var img = returnImage.Resize( size );
                img.Save( ms , format );
                return ms;
            }
        }
```

and this **ActionResult** :

```
    public FileStreamResult Image( long userkey , int? size )
    {
        var image = UserImagesService.Find( userkey );
        image.Size = size == null ? 0 : ( int )size;
        return new FileStreamResult( image.Stream , image.ContentType );
    }
```

when my size is null the image is load fine but when i pass size in firefox i see this error :

```
The image “http://localhost:8609/Profiles/Image/4006242570097652224/150” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

its fine saved on disk

what's my problem?

**UPDATE**

my resize functio :

```
    public static Image Resize( this Image imgToResize , int size )
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ( ( float )size / ( float )sourceWidth );
        nPercentH = ( ( float )size / ( float )sourceHeight );

        if( nPercentH < nPercentW )
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
        }

        int destWidth = ( int )( sourceWidth * nPercent );
        int destHeight = ( int )( sourceHeight * nPercent );

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap( destWidth , destHeight );
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( ( System.Drawing.Image )b );
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage( imgToResize , 0 , 0 , destWidth , destHeight );
        g.Dispose();

        return ( System.Drawing.Image )b;
    }
```

Comment: What does the `Resize` method do? It doesn't seem to be a method of `System.Drawing.Image`.

Comment: What are the specific errors you get?

Comment: i dont get any error in code but in browser didnt show the image and in firefox show me that error. **The image “http://localhost:8609/Profiles/Image/4006242570097652224/150” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another MemoryStream to save the resized image, and rewind that stream after saving the image data:

```
Image returnImage;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(PictureFile))
{
    returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
// leaving the using block closes ms

var img = returnImage.Resize(size);

// create new MemoryStream to save the resized image
var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(resultStream, format);

// rewind the stream
resultStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return resultStream;
```

When you write bytes to a stream, it advances its current [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position.aspx) by the number of bytes written (see for example the Remarks in [MemoryStream.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write.aspx)). Subsequent reading from the stream object will start from the same Position. Obviously when you want to read the previously written bytes, you need to rewind the stream to the position where writing started.

Comment: thanks man its work but can you show some reference or document about rewind the stream. why its needed? and ...